# HTML image (.jpeg) displaying in Safari, but not in Chrome

Tags: php, html, google-chrome, twitter, twitter-oauth

```
<img src="http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/2426066268/9kc5epnmtxj2hluczxw7_normal.jpeg" width="35" height="33" />
```

I used the Twitter API to generate the above code (using PHP). This image works perfectly on Safari, but refuses to work on Chrome.

Is there any setting that I am overseeing? Because there is no problem with the javascript and css. I checked by disabling both of them.

This problem has been bugging me for 3 days, it would be a huge huge favour if you help me :) Thanks in advance.

EDIT: For some reason the code has changed to an image here as well (in Safari and not in Chrome).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works fine in my Chrome.  You might try clearing your browser cache or restarting your browser.